# vscode tasks.json 2.0 g++ no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSC.

I've searched through stackoverflow, but can't find a question/solution relating to g++ error no such file or directory.  I encounter this problem when using tasks.json version 2.0.

It compiles and works if I invoke g++ on command line.

My Subclass.cpp file is located in this directory:
  "/home/superben/ESP32VSC/CodeExamples/Inheritance/", which is also in my c_cpp_properties.json file.

My c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "/home/superben/ESP32VSC/CodeExamples/Inheritance",
            "/usr/include/c++/7",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7",
            "/usr/include/c++/7/backward",
            "/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
            "/usr/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "/home/superben/ESP32VSC/CodeExamples/Inheritance/",
                "/usr/include/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/c++/7/backward",
                "/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.1/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17"
    },
```

My tasks.json file:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build subClass",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "Subclass.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

The output error from VSC build task:

```
> Executing task: g++ Subclass.cpp <

g++: error: Subclass.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I clearly am missing something simple with respect to setting up VSC so it can find the cpp file, but I can't figure out what it is, and none of the questions I've reviewed help resolve.  I don't have a Makefile, as I don't think that is required, but maybe that's the problem....

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: BTW - I'm on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Also, I don't have this problem on other VSC projects because they are all using the older version of tasks.json.  The one in this example is version 2.0.0, and the older versions are "version": "0.1.0", so I'm suspecting the tasks.json is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to do anything that would correct the build, so I ended up moving the code up from the ${workspaceFolder}/Inheritance to the ${workspaceFolder} directly, regardless of what "includePath" and "browse""path" I had defined in c_cpp_properties.json.  It also didn't matter whether I used a fully qualified directory structure, or the derived ${workspaceFolder} directory.

If the code wasn't in ${workspaceFolder} but was instead in a directory under that (e.g., ${workspaceFolder}/Inhertance, then it wasn't found.

So, it appears, from my limited knowledge and efforts, that all cpp code (didn't check if .h also constrained) has to be placed in the ${workspaceFolder} for the 'build task' to work correctly.

I was not using a Makefile in my tests, just the built in 'build task'.